# Scala: Why does SortedMap's mapValues returns a Map and not a SortedMap?

Tags: scala, dictionary, treemap, sortedmap

I'm new to Scala.
I'm using *[SortedMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SortedMap.html)* in my code, and I wanted to use *mapValues* to create a new map with some transformation on the values.

Instead of returning a new *[SortedMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SortedMap.html)*, the *mapValues* function returns a new *Map*, which I then have to convert to a *[SortedMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SortedMap.html)*.

For example

```
val my_map = SortedMap(1 -> "one", 0 -> "zero", 2 -> "two")
val new_map = my_map.mapValues(name => name.toUpperCase)
// returns scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(0 -> ZERO, 1 -> ONE, 2 -> TWO)
val sorted_new_map = SortedMap(new_map.toArray:_ *)
```

This looks inefficient - the last convertion probably sorts the keys again, or at least verify that they are sorted.

I could use the normal *map* function which operates both on the keys and the values, and deliberately not change the keys in my transformation function. This looks inefficient too, since the implementation of *Map* probably assume that the transformation may change the order of the keys (like in the case: `my_map.map(tup => (-tup._1, tup._2)`) - so it probably "re-sorts" them too.

Is anyone familiar with the internal implementations of *Map* and *[SortedMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/SortedMap.html)*, and could tell me if my assumptions are correct? Can the compiler recognize automatically that the keys have not been reordered? Is there an internal reason for why *mapValues* should not return a *SortedMap*? Is there a better way to transform the map's values without loosing the order of the keys?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've stumbled upon a tricky feature of Scala's `Map` implementation.  The catch that you are missing is that `mapValues` does not actually return a new `Map`: it returns a `view` of a `Map`.  In other words, it wraps your original map in such a way that whenever you access a value it will compute `.toUpperCase` before returning the value to you.

The upside to this behavior is that Scala won't compute the function for values that aren't accessed, and it won't spend time copying all the data into a new `Map`.  The downside is that the function is re-computed *every time* that value is accessed.  So you might end up doing *extra* computation if you access the same values many times.

So why does `SortedMap` not return a `SortedMap`?  Because it's actually returning a `Map`-wrapper.  The underlying `Map`, then one that is wrapped, is still a `SortedMap`, so if you were to iterate through, it would still be in sorted order.  You and I know that, but the type-checker doesn't.  It certainly seems like they could have written it in such a way that it still maintains the `SortedMap` trait, but they didn't.

You can see in the code that it's not returning a `SortedMap`, but that the iteration behavior is still going to be sorted:

```
// from MapLike
override def mapValues[C](f: B => C): Map[A, C] = new DefaultMap[A, C] {
  def iterator = for ((k, v) <- self.iterator) yield (k, f(v))
  ...
```

The solution to your problem is the same as the solution to getting around the view issue: use `.map{ case (k,v) => (k,f(v)) }`, as you mentioned in your question.

---

If you really want that convenience method though, you can do what I do, and write you own, better, version of `mapValues`:

```
class EnrichedWithMapVals[T, U, Repr <: GenTraversable[(T, U)]](self: GenTraversableLike[(T, U), Repr]) {
  /**
   * In a collection of pairs, map a function over the second item of each
   * pair.  Ensures that the map is computed at call-time, and not returned
   * as a view as 'Map.mapValues' would do.
   *
   * @param f   function to map over the second item of each pair
   * @return a collection of pairs
   */
  def mapVals[R, That](f: U => R)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[Repr, (T, R), That]) = {
    val b = bf(self.asInstanceOf[Repr])
    b.sizeHint(self.size)
    for ((k, v) <- self) b += k -> f(v)
    b.result
  }
}
implicit def enrichWithMapVals[T, U, Repr <: GenTraversable[(T, U)]](self: GenTraversableLike[(T, U), Repr]): EnrichedWithMapVals[T, U, Repr] =
  new EnrichedWithMapVals(self)
```

Now when you call `mapVals` on a `SortedMap` you get back a non-view `SortedMap`:

```
scala> val m3 = m1.mapVals(_ + 1)
m3: SortedMap[String,Int] = Map(aardvark -> 2, cow -> 6, dog -> 10)
```

It actually works on any collection of pairs, not just `Map` implementations:

```
scala> List(('a,1),('b,2),('c,3)).mapVals(_+1)
res8: List[(Symbol, Int)] = List(('a,2), ('b,3), ('c,4))
```

Comment: This is cool -- thanks.  I think it would still be nice if the standard library did the deed, because (as Oren suggested) it could presumably be considerably more efficient about it.  For example, a tree-based map could just duplicate the tree structure from the leaves toward the root, replacing the values as it went, rather than doing actual insertions, right?